# What do you call the end of a dock or pier that touches land?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

As in, "They stepped off the boat and ambled toward the ___ [of the dock]."

Comment: Docks usually have a *Gangway* to the shore. Piers are often connected to quays. "They stepped off the boat and ambled toward the quay."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **shore end**

> They stepped off the boat and ambled toward the **shore end** of the dock.

Here's an example of it in literary use:

> Rejoicing in Quork's continued good luck, his neighbors helped him unload his catch. There were trout, flounder, bluefish, and mullet. There were spot, croaker, redfish, and drum, but not a single trash fish in the lot. When they were loaded onto **the shore end of the dock**, they made a great pile. You could almost see the wheels turning in Quork's head as he tried to compute his profit on this one haul.

Source: ["Old Quork" by Charles Harry Whedbee](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=9LATBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=%22shore-end+of+the+dock%22&source=bl&ots=mz2vsbJCTC&sig=M2Av3kCm4T1MIH3_sR5zgSJkt3o&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22shore-end%20of%20the%20dock%22&f=false)

And here's an [example](http://www.seattle.gov/dpd/cs/groups/pan/@pan/documents/web_informational/s047940.pdf) of it in technical use:

> Conspicuous signage shall be located at the fire apparatus access road termination point and **the shore end** of piers, wharves and floats.

Alternatively, you could just say:

> They stepped off the boat and ambled along the dock toward dry land.

Comment: Apologies for the late accept. I forgot I asked this!